# Can someone explain the syntax in the geb Page content DSL?

Tags: groovy, syntax, spock, dsl, geb

I have problems to understand the syntax with which pages are described (defined) in Geb. The following is an example page class that works fine but I don't understand how it works.

```
import geb.Page

class GebHomePage extends Page{
    static url = "http://gebish.org"

    static at = { title == "Geb - Very Groovy Browser Automation" }

    static content = {
        seeGuideButton { $('div', class:'ui huge primary button') }
        uiHeader { $('h1', class:'ui header', 0)}
    }
}
```

I am interested in the syntax inside the closure referred to by content. Geb describes the syntax for the content DSL as

```
«name»(«options map») { «definition» }
```

I don't understand this syntax. The name part looks like a variable, but it is not declared (I miss a def or something similar) and the last part looks like a closure. But where is the connection between the name and the closure. There is no equal sign connecting the two. In a standard groovy class the syntax

```
«name» { «definition» }
```

does not compile. What happens in one line of the content DSL? What precisely are `uiHeader` and `seeGuideButton` and how are they related to the following closures? How does this syntax work exactly?

Answer (score 5):

Behind the scenes, Geb looks for a method with the signature:

```
uiHeader(Map, Closure)
```

In groovy, you can catch when a method is missing (see methodMissing) so internally Geb will catch this and know how to resolve any future requests for that variable

Also in groovy, a Closure as the last parameter can be outside the brackets, which is why you can do

```
uiHeader(required: false) { $('h1') }
```

Comment: And just for reference, the `methodMissing()` handling content definitions can be found in `PageContentTemplateBuilder` at https://github.com/geb/geb/blob/09d4a5c5dabec9d461e7901c21fd717faf4ae336/module/geb-core/src/main/groovy/geb/content/PageContentTemplateBuilder.groovy#L78